# How long is the after-shutter-press delay when taking a flash picture with the S21 Ultra?

Tags: flash

I can't think of anything to add to the wording in the Title.

But in case the answer is disappointing: Can anyone suggest specific mobile phones (or failing that,  point-and-shoot cameras) that have virtually instantaneous flash?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? How about some words to explain  why you are asking the question.

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/why-do-i-have-shutter-lag-when-shooting-pop-up-flash-in-manual-mode

Comment: Alaska Man: I'm asking because I want to photograph something that disappears before my current phone can flash. I know there are lots of ways of attacking this problem, but I've dug into many of them and at the moment am only investigating what flash can do .I ask about the S21 Ultra in particular because some of its other features appeal to me.

Comment: techolic: Thanks for the link. It gave me several useful factors to keep in mind.

Comment: Rather than using a phone with faster flash, could maybe use a flashlight or other external light source to illuminate the subject?

Comment: @wilkgr Most "flashes" on phones aren't really flashes at all, they're LEDs that come on before the (electronic) shutter opens and don't go off until after the image is done.

Comment: @MichaelC I'm aware of this; I'm only aware of a Nokia windows phone that had an actual xenon flash. By 'faster flash' I meant one that doesn't have the delay that OP was aiming to reduce.

Comment: wilgr:  I've tried an external light but the subjects find it distracting. I was hoping that a flash (LED) would be quick enough that they could ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly variable, depending on the shooting options selected and the shooting conditions. A lot goes on between pressing the button and taking the image. If you haven't pre-focused, and you're in very low light it could take several seconds. If you've pre-focused and are in bright light, it should only take a few tens of milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I was hoping the S21 Ultra's improved autofocus, as mentioned in various reviews, would speed things up without pre-focus, but I guess there's no substitute for trying it out in real world conditions.